# End Function Doesn't Return a Value on All Code Paths

Tags: function, visual-studio-2012

I have a green squiggle under the "End Function" it prompts me, saying "Are you missing a return statement?" When I do indeed have a return statement. Here is what I have:

```
Private Function TaxCalcFunc(ByVal propVal As Decimal, ByVal perc As Decimal, ByVal rate As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim AssessedValue As Decimal
    Dim Tax As Decimal
    Try
        AssessedValue = propVal * perc
        Tax = AssessedValue / 100 * rate
        Return Tax
        If rate > 1 Or perc > 1 Then
            Throw New Exception("Tax Greater Than Value. Did you use the decimal Point?")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(0)

    End Try
    'I was unable to get rid of the green squiggle for some reason, says I am missing a return statement
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a `return` statement inside or after the `Catch` statement so if an exception was thrown before the `Return Tax` code then your function would indeed not return a value.